# Event target value returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When the value of the event is printed from a TextInput in React Native, the `event.target` is an integer and the `event.target.value` is undefined.

The code I am using is below:

```
<TextInput
  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
  style={styles.input}
  type="text"
  name={serviceId}
  data-id={idx}
  id={serviceId}
  value={props.services[idx].name}
  className="name"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To grab the value you want to use

```
onChangeText={(value) => console.log(value)}
```

[Check the docs for more info](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html)